# More memory-optimised version of Bitmap.createScaledBitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview

I fully understand that *"premature optimization is the root of all evil.*" However, I have gotten to a point where I believe that the optimization I wish to do can no longer be considered "premature".

I'm writing an Android application that, among other things, streams a live image feed from a USB device, performs some image processing with OpenCV, converts the frame into a bitmap, and then renders that bitmap to a SurfaceView in real time.

I got everything working, (the live feed is correctly rendered to the SurfaceView) and Android Studio's "Profiler" tool indicates that I've done my memory management well (notice that the garbage collector **does not run once in the 10 seconds shown below**):

[image]

However, because the image I'm streaming is low resolution (320x180), when I render it directly to the SurfaceView, it actually ends up being physically pretty small on the device's screen.

Thus, I decided to scale the bitmap to the maximum size that would fit in the SurfaceView before rendering it to the screen. However, after doing this, I was horrified to find that the memory usage graph now looks horrendous! (The garbage collector **runs more than once per second!**)

[image]

Here are the relevant snippets of code:

- Before scaling the bitmap (clean memory graph):

  ```
  canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
  openCvMat = frameQueue.take();
  Utils.matToBitmap(openCvMat, bitmapFromMat);
  mat.release();
  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapFromMat, 0, 0, null);
  getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
  ```
- After scaling the bitmap (horrendous memory graph):

  ```
  canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
  openCvMat = frameQueue.take();
  Utils.matToBitmap(openCvMat, bitmapFromMat);
  mat.release();
  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
  Bitmap scaled = scaleBitmapToViewport(bitmapFromMat);
  canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
  scaled.recycle();
  getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
  ```
- `scaleBitmapToViewport()` method:

  ```
  private Bitmap scaleBitmapToViewport(Bitmap bitmap)
  {
      //Landscape
      if((canvas.getHeight() * aspectRatio) < canvas.getWidth())
      {
          return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) Math.round(canvas.getHeight() * aspectRatio), canvas.getHeight(), true);
      }
      else //Portrait
      {
          return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, canvas.getWidth(), (int) Math.round(canvas.getWidth() / aspectRatio), true);
      }
  }
  ```

So it seems that `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` is the culprit. Does anyone know another method to accomplish the same that doesn't give the garbage collector a run for its money?

Comment: Instead of scaling the bitmap itself like you're doing - can't you scale *while drawing*?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)

I'm looking at canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) - note that it takes both source and destination rectangles. You'll want to set the source to your (small) image dimensions and the dest to the dimensions of your surface.

Comment: @KostyaVasilyev Aha, that worked! However, I still wonder if there's a bug in the `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` method that caused it to "leak" memory. (Yes I know it's not really a *leak* but you get the idea)

Comment: Regarding the memory usage patterns: you're creating a new scaled bitmap every time through the loop. That's regular allocations of (fairly large, I assume) amounts of memory, so there you are.

Comment: @KostyaVasilyev But I'm still doing that with adding OpenCV Mat objects to a queue 30 times per second. Besides, you can see that the garbage collector was being invoked, even though I was manually releasing the memory with `bitmap.recycle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scaling the bitmap itself like you're doing - can't you scale while drawing?

I'm looking at [canvas.drawBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)) (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) - note that it takes both source and destination rectangles.

You'll want to set the source to your (small) image dimensions and the dest to the dimensions of your surface.